# Checking if two characters are equal to each other in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to find a missing letter in an array of letters of alphabetical order. ex. [a,b,c,d,f] missing => 'e'.

Right now I have this:

```
def find_missing_letter(chars):

    # Creates variables of complete alphabet.

    alphabetLower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    enumeratedLower = []
    alphabetUpper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    enumeratedUpper = []

    # Checks if the function has to enumerate the upper- or lowercase alphabet.

    if(chars[0].islower()):
        for c, value in enumerate(alphabetLower, 1):
            enumeratedLower.append([c, value])
    else:
        for c, value in enumerate(alphabetUpper, 1):
            enumeratedUpper.append([c, value])

    # Checks at what letter the characters begin. 
    # After that it checks if the following letters are equal to eachother.

    if(chars[0].isupper()):
        for x in range(1, 26):
            print enumeratedUpper[x][1]
            print 'char:' + chars[0]
            if(chars[0] == enumeratedUpper[x][1]):
                for i in range(enumeratedUpper[x][0], len(chars)):
                    if(chars[i] != alphabetUpper[i]):
                        return alphabetUpper[i]
    else:
        for x in range(1, 26):
            print enumeratedLower[x][1]
            print 'char:' + chars[0]
            if(chars[0] == enumeratedLower[x][1]):
                for i in range(enumeratedLower[x][0], len(chars)):
                    if(chars[i] != alphabetLower[i]):
                        return alphabetLower[i]
```

However, the if statements

```
if(chars[0] == enumeratedUpper[x][1]):
```

and

```
if(chars[0] == enumeratedLower[x][1]):
```

are not working for some reason. The reason for this statement is because a given array of characters (chars), can start at a random letter (doesn't have to start at 'a' or 'A'). I put the print statement there to see what was wrong and the output is this:

```
b
char:o
c
char:o
d
char:o
e
char:o
f
char:o
g
char:o
h
char:o
i
char:o
j
char:o
k
char:o
l
char:o
m
char:o
n
char:o
o
char:o
p
char:o
q
char:o
r
char:o
s
char:o
t
char:o
u
char:o
v
char:o
w
char:o
x
char:o
y
char:o
z
char:o
```

Comment: This code is pretty confusing, but, for one thing: arrays start at 0. Therefore, the reason you're skipping the letter 'a' is because your loop goes from 1 to 25.

Comment: Do you just want to find the first gap? Or can there be multiple gaps? Are the input letters guaranteed to be in order?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted program does not produce the given output: it defines a function, but never calls it.  Also, you asked two functionally unrelated questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things a bit.
There is no need to handle upper and lowercase letters separately.
Also, you don't have to use `enumerate` just use `index` method to find 
where characters begin.

```
import string 

def find_missing_letter(chars):   
    # Creates variables of complete alphabet.
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase if chars[0].islower() else string.ascii_uppercase
    # Checks at what letter the characters begin
    start = alphabet.index(chars[0])
    # After that it checks if the following letters are equal to each other.
    for x, y in zip(chars, aplhabet[start:]):
        if x != y:
            return y
```

Sample output:

```
>>> find_missing_letter('abcdf')
'e'
```

Comment: You're completely right. thank you for the help! I can't believe I didn't think of the .index() function -,-

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be too complicated. Just convert the list of chars to list of nums using `map` and `ord`, then enumerate the resulting list to find the first missing number, convert it back to char using `chr`

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
chr(next(i for i,j in enumerate(map(ord, l), ord(l[0])) if i!=j))
'e'
```

Comment: I like this answer but it does raise a `StopIteration` if there isn't a letter missing as in `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 0):

You may search the letters that are not in chars, using a generator expression, and then sort them if you need them in alphabetic order

```
>>> chars = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f']
>>> alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase if chars[0].islower() else string.ascii_uppercase
>>> sorted(letter for letter in alphabet if letter not in chars and letter > chars[0] and letter < chars[-1])

['c', 'e']
```